# Why when i push button that have onclick="function.js" my metamask dont react

Tags: javascript, transactions, onclick, metamask

I've got problem with etherium transaction using metamask.
This is my function of transaction

```
function send_eth() {
  var home_wallet = wallet(i dont want to show wallet, but its correct);
  var value = document.getElementById("inputCost").value;
  console.log(value);
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
    to: home_wallet,
    value: value
  }, console.log);
}
```

and this is my button

```
<button type="submit" id="send_eth"  onclick="send_eth()" class="btn btn-dark">Создать</button>
```

I have checked in browser console and metamask react on the code, but when I put it in function it doesn't react.

Comment: What is the console output? Any errors? (Please edit your question to include this information.)

Comment: Also it's possible that you are navigating away from the page before it can react, due to the default action of the button. Try passing the `event` variable to the function (add `event` as argument) and then calling `event.preventDefault()` on it.